# Numpy fft not giving expected results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I am trying to find the frequency spectrum in a current signal from a solenoid being driven by a 100Hz PWM driver. The signal is sampled at 19200 Hz.

The following is a plot of the signal . The signal is a part of a longer time series data. 1024 data points are extracted form the 22 second point.

[Current Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUZan.png)

The following code is used for the analysis

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,y)

Fs=19200              # (Hz) sampling rate
N=len(y)   # length of signal
time=N/Fs #total time of signal, 1/time is the fundamantal frequency
freq=np.arange(N)/time  # frequency vector for fft spectrum plot
freq=freq[0:int(N/2)]  # one sided frequecy
Y=np.fft.fft(y)/N*2     # fft of signal
Y=Y[0:int(N/2)]         # one sided frequency

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(freq,abs(Y))  # one sided frequency plot

plt.xlabel("Hz")
plt.ylabel("Units")
plt.title("FFT spectrum")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

One would expect a dominant 100 Hz component in the spectrum but the numpy fft results do not reflect that. Following is the `numpy.fft` frequency plot.

[FFT Spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRrEH.png)

Following is a plot form Matlab fft analysis for similar signal. As expected there is a dominant 100Hz component and it harmonics.

[Signal for Matlab fft analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoujb.jpg)

[Matlab FFT spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9zAp.jpg)

Comment: obviously the second image is just your data with a different scale. no fft has been computed. check in your code if you haven't typed `y` instead of `Y`. there's no typo here, but that's the only explanation

Comment: Please always run the code you post here. The posted code obviously didn't generate the given graphs. Read read more about this: [mcve].

Comment: I have tested the code with the test data signal (T=1, t=np.arange(0,T,1/Fs), y=2 + 4*np.sin(3*2*np.pi*t)+13*np.sin(9*2*np.pi*t) and numpy fft correctly identifies the DC component of 2 and  3Hz and 9Hz sine components with the corresponding amplitudes. I am not sure why fft is not computed correctly on the current signal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to perform the Discrete Fourier Transform on a function for which you already know the analytical result. Once you are satisfied with what you see, than you run the some lines of code on something for which you don't know the result, as I've already done in this discussion

[Numerical Fourier Transform of rectangular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686490/numerical-fourier-transform-of-rectangular-function/40695196#40695196)

As you can see, both in Matlab and Python a shift of the right side of the spectrum ( fftshift(y) ) has to be performed before and after the Numerical Fourier Transform.

You may also be interested into the so-called Nyquist theorem, which states the minimum sampling frequency for which the Numerical Fourier Transform can be applied, but I don't think this is your problem at the moment as the sampling frequency of your spectrum looks quite high.

By the way, the right way to perform a Fast Fourier Transform on a step function using python is reported in what follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
y[200:400] = 1
# Step function for which the Fourier Transform is well known to be sin(x)/x
yShift = np.fft.fftshift(y) 
# Shift of the N/2 sampling data on the right side to the left side
fftyShift = np.fft.fft(yShift)
# Numerical Fourier Transform (Lanczos)
ffty = np.fft.fftshift(fftyShift)
# Shift of the N/2 transformed data on the right side to the left side

plt.plot(ffty)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to use `ifftshift` to shift the signal before the FFT. This function differs from `fftshift` if the signal is odd in length. Also, it is only necessary to use this if the origin is specifically defined to be in the center of the signal, rather than the left edge. `fftshift` after the FFT is likewise only necessary if one wants to see the zero frequency in the middle of the plotted graph, it is not at all necessary in general. -- That said, this does not really answer the question because OP didn't apply the FFT at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefano. But it still does not solve the issue.